# how to configure two ip blocks for use on a network

Tags: networking, ip, linux-networking, subnet

My ISP has given me a /30 and a /27 ip block I can use. for the sake of not giving out my ips I'll use 192.168.1.192/30 and 192.169.1.224/27. I'm not using a router in my setup, I only have a switch. Right now I do not have the possibility to use a hardware router so please dont hassle me about that.

So here is what I have:

- On a debian server I have it set to 192.168.1.194, subnet: 255.255.255.252, gateway: 192.168.1.193, DNS 8.8.8.8
- On a centos server i have 192.169.1.226, subnet 255.255.255.224, gateway 192.168.1.194
- On my windows 7 laptop i have 192.169.1.227, subnet 255.255.255.224, gateway 192.168.1.194

I can access the internet from the first debian server however I cant access anything on any of the other machines.

I've tried setting the gateways on the centos & windows machines to either 192.168.1.194 and 192.168.1.193 but that doesn't fix the problem. Is there something obvious I'm missing with this config?

My guess is that I need to configure the debian server as a router since it has the main ip address but how do I do that? Ive already enabled ipv4 forwardign on the debian server.

Also note that the ISP uplink is a GigE fiber connection and none of my servers has a fiber nic to connect to.

Comment: What kind of switch do you have?

Comment: netgear prosafe gs110TP a gigabit switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like that. **Server 1** needs iptables [configuration for security](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo), <strike>and also [NAT](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialIptablesNetworkGateway.html)</strike>. As said by others, [ipv4.forwarding must be enabled](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-under.html).

[image: Network Topology]

**EDIT**: As Frederik Nielsen commented, you don't need any NAT if every device of your network has its own public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Do either of your linux boxes have two nics?

You can use them as a hardware router quite easily.

You'll want to [enable ipv4 forwarding](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/).

Even if they don't currently have a second NIC, adding one is pretty trivial and cheap.  Beyond that, you are going to have a mess on your hands.

Comment: I should have said I already have ip forwarding turned on

Comment: So, take the uplink from your ISP, connect it to NIC one on your linux box.  Take NIC two and connect it into the switch.  Plug the other two hosts into the switch.  Bang, linux router.  Now setup an RFC 1918 LAN, enable NAT and you are good to go.

Comment: the problem here is that the uplink is a gige fiber connection and I cant connect it to the server.

Comment: He means take the fiber handoff from your ISP. The /30 network - one is assigned to port on the device the ISP is using for the fiber handoff, the other is assigned to one NIC on your linux box that you are going to use as the router.

Comment: my debian server does not have a fiber nic so I cant do that.

Comment: So, how are you connecting to it now?

Comment: via the switch. My switch has 2 fiber ports

Comment: Then you could setup vlans on the switch - one between the fibre port and the port the server acting as router uses and one for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

The /30 can have 1 host plus a gateway.  The other can support up to 29 hosts plus your gateway.  If your provider only gave you one gateway address they most likely expect you to use a host in the /30 block as the router for the other block.

These are 2 separate network blocks.  Hosts in the larger block have no way to talk to the gateway address in the smaller block without some sort of a router.  If your debian host has an additional interface you could use it as a router but there be aware that done improperly you could open your hosts to malicious activity.

At minimum you will need to:

1. Setup an additional address in the larger network on the debian host.  This can be a separate NIC or a subinterface.
2. Turn on ipv4.forwarding
3. Configure iptables to allow the traffic to pass through the debian host.
4. Use the address from the first step as the gateway for the remaining hosts.

Comment: Can you post in your answer how to set one of the nics in the debian server as a router?